# Unable to give input in phone number textbox in SafariIOS Simulator

Tags: javascript, protractor, appium, appium-ios, saucelabs

I have scenario where I need to enter phone number in text box field, using SafariIOS simulator but am getting invalid phone number error even through number is not inputting.  Can someone please help me on this.
I am using appium for intracting with SafariIOS through simulator find below configuration code for appium with saucelabs integration code.

**Configuration code**

```
SafariIOS: {
        appiumVersion: '1.20.1',
        deviceName: 'iPhone Simulator',
        deviceOrientation: 'portrait',
       "shardTestFiles": true,
       "maxInstances": 15,
        browserName: 'Safari',
        platformVersion: '14.3',
        platformName: 'iOS'
}
```

Below is the code I have written and issue is only with safariIOS browser. It is working for android.
**code :**

```
element(by.css('input#tel')).sendKeys(Number(9874563296))
element(by.css('input#tel')).sendKeys("9876543218");
```

**error image** :

[image]

**html elements**

```
<div class="mat-form-field-infix ng-tns-c57-38"><input matinput="" class="mat-input-element mat-form-field-autofill-control ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid cdk-text-field-autofill-monitored ng-star-inserted" type="tel" required="" id="tel" aria-required="true"><!----><!----><span class="mat-form-field-label-wrapper ng-tns-c57-38"><label class="mat-form-field-label ng-tns-c57-38 mat-empty mat-form-field-empty ng-star-inserted" id="mat-form-field-label-19" for="tel" aria-owns="tel"><!----><mat-label class="ng-tns-c57-38 ng-star-inserted"> Phone <span class="required-star ng-star-inserted">* </span><!----></mat-label><!----><!----><span aria-hidden="true" class="mat-placeholder-required mat-form-field-required-marker ng-tns-c57-38 ng-star-inserted"> *</span><!----></label><!----></span></div>
<input matinput="" class="mat-input-element mat-form-field-autofill-control ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid cdk-text-field-autofill-monitored ng-star-inserted" type="tel" required="" id="tel" aria-required="true">
```

**additional info**
when am trying to enter number in text box , number is not able to enter that means number is not inputting. as this number is not entering hence create account button is not enabled , if all fields enter values then only create button will enabled . in this scenario as number is not taking into phone number text field  to enter value(number). the same code is working for Android emulator . i want to is there any restriction in SafariIOS. please find below code and snips .

### element(by.css('')).senkeys('raj1234@gmail.com') element(by.css('')).senkeys('raj') element(by.css('')).senkeys('beeram') element(by.css('')).senkeys('passwors@!231') element(by.css('input#tel')).sendKeys("9876543218");  browser.executeScript("arguments[0].click()",createAccountButton);

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOTLx.png)

Comment: Can you share more of your automation code; what happens between the call to `sendKeys` and form submission?

Comment: when am trying to enter number in text box , number is not able to enter that means number is not inputting.

Comment: added code and image in the description as additional info section, please check and help me.